# Prove by induction $(x+y)^n ≥ \frac{x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}}{x-y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction

> Suppose that $x,y\in\Bbb R$ with $x>y>0$. Prove by induction that
>   $$(x+y)^n ≥ \frac{x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}}{x-y}\ \forall n\in\Bbb N$$

How do I prove starting from $n=1$ as I won't be able to get 1 because I don't know $x$ and $y$ value

Comment: Tip: Start with $n=0$.

Comment: $ x^0 = 1 $ so you don't have to know what x and y are at the start.

Comment: Although you can start with $n=0$ but is n't the inequality obvious even for $n=1$ ?

Comment: @ArpitKansal: You should probably refrain from using the term "obvious" since it is clear that the OP couldn't come to the statement for $n=1$.

Comment: Dear @FaraadArmwood: Thanks,i used 'obvious' because it was just a matter of calculation with no idea at all!

Comment: @ArpitKansal: I understand. I was just pointing it out because it could be discouraging for someone trying to understand something and people say something is obvious, or a result simply follows. No harm done.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @MartinSleziak the title is perfectly fine.

Comment: @QthePlatypus Which title do you mean? The title [after my edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1964794/revisions) or the original title: "Prove by induction help !!!!?"

Comment: Ah didn't realise you edited the title.

Comment: Dear @FaraadArmwood:You have a good point there,i'll take care of that.Thank you!

Comment: @ArpitKansal can you tell me how should i start - prove by induction 9| (4^(3n)-1) for all n ∈ N

Answer (score 1):

Substituting n = 0 then

$$ (x+y)^0 \geq \frac{x^1 - y^1}{x - y} $$

Which gives $ 1 \geq 1 $ which is true.

Comment: how should i start - prove by induction 9| (4^(3n)-1) for all n ∈ N

Answer (score 0):

If $n=1$ then the RHS is $(x+y)^1$ and the LHS is;

$$\frac{(x^2-y^2)}{(x-y)} = \frac{(x+y)(x-y)}{(x-y)} = x+y$$